# Combining two data sources with exact same schema in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two data sources containing list of orders with the exact field structure (one is the archive, and another is the active database). I'm accessing them through OData connection in Tableau.

What I want is to combine these two data sources so the Tableau chart will display all order numbers and information (as opposed to just the active one, which I'm doing with a single data source).

The two tables don't overlap (since whatever is archived is by definition not active), so I cannot join or blend with the primary key Order No. (or any key for that matter).

How can I combine these data sources? Does the fact that the connection is OData make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

For relational databases, the solution is to define custom SQL with two back to back select statements (1 for each table) separated by the SQL UNION ALL keywords

I don't know whether OData sources support UNION ALL

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately I don't see an option for Custom SQL for OData sources, but I will attempt this for another part that uses Excel.

Comment: Excel on windows supports Union with the legacy driver. Not on Mac yet. But if you load your excel data into Postgres, MySQL or another relational database, then you can use custom SQL and UNION ALL

Comment: The other option is to have one table with a Boolean flag to separate archived and active records.

Answer (score 1):

Create TDE file for Archive data and add this file to the current data extract using the option "Append data from file" from Data-->Extract;